# Understanding Modified Baugh-Wooley multiplication algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, binary, logic, multiplication

For Modified Baugh-Wooley multiplication algorithm , why is it !(A0*B5) instead of just (A0*B5) ?

Same questions for !(A1*B5), !(A2*B5), !(A3*B5), !(A4*B5), !(A5*B4), !(A5*3), !(A5*B2), !(A5*B1) and !(A5*B0)

Besides, why there are two extra '1'  ?

[image: Modified Baugh-Wooley multiplication algorithm]

Comment: I think I understand why flipping the values of some of the partial product bits. It is due to signed bit in the MSB (A5 and B5). However, I still do not understand how to get the two extra '1'

Comment: Ok, I think I also got why two extra '1'. Note : '-2' in two complement is 110

Comment: Besides, this method also does not require sign extension which sometimes take up hardware space in some small hardware devices.

Comment: Someone else had coded the modified baugh-wooley algo in verilog. So, if anyone is interested, see https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/555.php

But do remember the time complexity of this algo remains at O(N) unless we combine this algo with Row Adder tree mechanism as described in http://www.andraka.com/multipli.php (O(logN))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why two extra '1'?

See some previous explanation in Matt Timmermans's answer

Note : '-2' in two complement is 110, and this contributes to the carries, thus two extra '1'

> why flipping the values of some of the partial product bits.

It is due to signed bit in the MSB (A5 and B5).

Besides, please see below the Countermeasure for modified baugh-wooley algorithm in the case of A_WIDTH != B_WIDTH with the help of [others](https://www.reddit.com/r/algorithms/comments/ar40e4/modified_baughwooley_multiplication_algorithm_for/).

[image: Countermeasure for modified baugh-wooley algorithm in the case of A_WIDTH != B_WIDTH]

I have written a [hardware verilog code](https://gist.github.com/promach/5f2d9a9494704ed93cf65687c982198c#file-multiply-v) for this algorithm
Hopefully, this post helps some readers.

Comment: I am wondering how [the divide-and-conquer approach](https://www.ece.ucsb.edu/~parhami/pres_folder/f31-book-arith-pres-pt3.pdf#page=75) would work with my above countermeasure.

@matt-timmermans What do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

In signed 6-bit 2s complement notation, the place values of the bits are:

```
-32  16   8   4   2   1
```

Notice that the top bit has a negative value.  When addition, subtraction, and multiplication are performed mod 64, however, that minus sign makes absolutely no difference to how those operations work, because 32 = -32 mod 64.

Your multiplication is *not* being performed mod 64, though, so that sign must be taken into account.

One way to think of your multiplication is that the 6-bit numbers are extended to 12 bits, and multiplication is then performed mod 4096.  When extending a signed number, the top bit is replicated, so -32 becomes -2048 + 1024 + 512 ... +32,  which all together has the same value of -32.  So extend the signed numbers and multiply.  I'll do it with 3 bits, multiplying mod 64:

```
Given:         Sign-extended:
A2 A1 A0       A2 A2 A2 A2 A1 A0
B2 B1 B0       B2 B2 B2 B2 B1 B0

Multiply:
A0B2    A0B2    A0B2    A0B2    A0B1   A0B0
A1B2    A1B2    A1B2    A1B1    A1B0        
A2B2    A2B2    A2B1    A2B0
A2B2    A2B1    A2B0
A2B1    A2B0
A2B0
```

Since we replicated the same bits in multiple positions, you'll see the same bit products at multiple positions.

A0B2 appears 4 times with with total place value 60 or 15<<2, and so on.  Let write the multipliers in:

```
                        A0B2*15 A0B1   A0B0
                A1B2*7  A1B1    A1B0        
        A2B2*5  A2B1*7  A2B0*15
```

Again, because of modular arithmetic, the *15s and *7s are the same as *-1, and the *5 is the same as *1:

```
                       -A0B2    A0B1   A0B0
               -A1B2    A1B1    A1B0        
        A2B2   -A2B1   -A2B0
```

That pattern is starting to look familiar.  Now, of course -1 is not a bit value, but ~A0B2 = 1-A0B2, so we can translate -A0B2 into ~A0B2 and then subtract the extra 1 we added. If we do this for all the subtracted products:

```
                       ~A0B2    A0B1   A0B0
               ~A1B2    A1B1    A1B0        
        A2B2   ~A2B1   ~A2B0
                 -2       -2
```

If we add up the place values of those -2s and expand them into the equivalent bits, we discover the source of the additional 1s in your diagram:

```
                       ~A0B2    A0B1   A0B0
               ~A1B2    A1B1    A1B0        
        A2B2   ~A2B1   ~A2B0
   1              1
```

Comment: "One way to think of your multiplication is that the 6-bit numbers are extended to 12 bits, and multiplication is then performed mod 4096."  <-- why extend to 12 bits ?

Comment: because it takes 12 bits to hold the product of two 6-bit numbers without overflow.  63*63=3069.  With signed numbers you could actually get away with 11 bits, but they went to 12 in your example.

Comment: "A0B2 appears 4 times with with total place value 60 or 15<<2" <-- what do you exactly mean by total place value ? and how do you obtain 60 or 15<<2 ?

Comment: Just like with grade school addition, each of the columns has a place value.  A0B2, appears once in each of the 4s, 8s, 16s, and 32s columns, for a total value of 60.  60=15*4, so that's the same as the bit pattern for 15 shifted two bits left,  That's why I write *15 in the 4s column.

Comment: " because of modular arithmetic, the *15s and *7s are the same as *-1, and the *5 is the same as *1"   <-- We are discussing multiplication here, WHY is MODULO arithmetic involved here ?

Comment: And how is "the *5 is the same as *1" ever be possible ?

Comment: modular arithmetic is involved because we're only producing a fixed number of bits.  5 would normally be 101, but the top bit is thrown away.

Comment: "fixed number of bits"  ?  <-- how many bits exactly are you referring to in the case of 3-bit by 3-bit multiplication above ? In other words, how do you determine the number of bits to be retained in the modulo arithmetic shown in some of previous comments above ?

Comment: 6 bits altogether - that's how many columns I drew.  Because it takes 6 bits to store the result of a 3x3 multiplication without overflow. I think I've answered this question before.  The 101 is shifted left by 4 places, though, so only 2 bits of it are kept

Comment: " The 101 is shifted left by 4 places, though, so only 2 bits of it are kept"  <-- the LEAST Significant Bit is ZERO or '0' due to left shift operation , so how is that possible that we can still get *1 from *5 ?

Comment: the *5 is originally located at the 16s column as shown in your answer post, I do not understand how a left shift by 4 bits ended up in *1 for A2B2 at the 16s column ? Why are you NOT assuming that the LSB of *5 is at the 16s column ?

Comment: hi Matt, I have converted the modified baugh-wooley algorithm into verilog hardware code. Are you familiar with verilog ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646347/modified-baugh-wooley-algorithm-multiply-verilog-code-does-not-multiply-correctl

Comment: It seems like modified baugh-wooley algorithm only works for multiplicand[A_WIDTH-1:0] and multiplier[B_WIDTH-1:0] where A_WIDTH == B_WIDTH .  this means I could not build a 6-bit by 4-bit multiplication code using modified baugh-wooley algorithm. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: To build a 6x4 multplier you can build a 6x6 multiplier, but replicate the sign bit of the short word 3 times, and ignore the top 2 bits of the result.

Comment: But are there ways to avoid the need for sign replication of the short word ?

Comment: I have modified a little bit more on the "modified baugh-wooley algorithm" to handle the signed multiplication in the case of multiplicand_width != multiplier_width without replicating the sign bit of the short word, thus saving hardware resources or area. See the [hardware verilog code](https://gist.github.com/promach/5f2d9a9494704ed93cf65687c982198c/339430207a89f1dfb7bae9bf10dc4577d9419b9e#file-multiply-v-L150-L186) I have done using this further modification. I will post a detailed answer this weekend with more maths details on this further modification

Comment: The countermeasure I have posted a day ago does not handle all numbers, rendering the countermeasure useless. I will put the countermeasure there until something else is found without replicating the sign bit of the short word. What do you have in mind ?

Comment: What do you think about [this other countermeasure](https://www.reddit.com/r/algorithms/comments/ar40e4/modified_baughwooley_multiplication_algorithm_for/egl46ml) done by someone else ?

Comment: @MattTimmermans For https://www.reddit.com/r/algorithms/comments/ar40e4/modified_baughwooley_multiplication_algorithm_for/egm8wyd/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 ,  why the value for !A0B5 results in !(0*B5) which is 1  ?
and the value for A1B4 results in zero 0*B4 so that column is left with a 1 ?

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that's because how [2's-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation works: the top bit is effectively a sign bit so `1` there means `-`. In other words you have to subtract

```
A5*(B4 B3 B2 B1 B0) << 5
```

and

```
B5*(A4 A3 A2 A1 A0) << 5
```

from the sum (note that `A5*B5` is added again because both have the same `-` sign). And those two `1` is the result of substituting those two subtractions with additions of `-X`.

If you need more details, then you probably just need to re-read how 2's-complement work and then the whole math behind the Baugh-Wooley multiplication algorithm. It is not that complicated.

Comment: A6*B6 is added again ? This is not highlighted in https://www.ece.ucsb.edu/~parhami/pres_folder/f31-book-arith-pres-pt3.pdf#page=62

Comment: @kevin998x Sorry, I messed up with the starting index. It should have been `A5`/`B5` instead of `A6`/`B6`. I fixed my answer. Also you can see that in your image the `A5 B5` term is without negation.

Comment: Why subtract

(A5*(B4 B3 B2 B1 B0) << 5)  ?

Comment: @kevin998x  Which part you don't understand? Why subtract? Or why `<<5`? Subtract because this is what the real meaning of the top bit in 2's-complement is.  Shift left by 5 bits because there are 5 bits below `A5`: `(A5 0 0 0 0 0) * (B4 B3 B2 B1 B0)` = `A5*(B4 B3 B2 B1 B0) << 5`

Comment: "Subtract because this is what the real meaning of the top bit in 2's-complement is."  <-- what ? changing to two complement only requires flipping the bits and adding '1'. Why subtract ?

Comment: @kevin998x, sorry, you really should go back to 2's-complement first and understand the logic of how it really works and specifically what the top bit there means. Not how to get it, but how and why it works. Before that it is too early to try to understand the algorithm to multiply 2's-complement values.